# Asp.Net C# Mysql Select Query with Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need to get data from database . I added some parameters in my SQL. 
When I try to execute this sql , I got zero record.
Which is my code;

```
        MysqlCon c = new MysqlCon();
        MySqlConnection con = c.GetMySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
        con.Open();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KASA WHERE KUL_AD=@AD ";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AD", "egemenhalici@gmail.com");
        int rc = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

If I write this sql without any parameters, I am getting datas.

What am I doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: Might be because there is no data which has `KUL_AD = egemenhalici@gmail.com` ?

Comment: If I write "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KASA WHERE KUL_AD='egemenhalici@gmail.com'"  I am getting data.

Comment: But are you getting 0 as a result? or a number

Comment: After execute codes,the rc variable is being 0.But It sholud be 1

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the right database in your code?

Comment: Maybe you need single quotes around `@AD` in your command text.

Comment: Yes sir.I am sure to connect right database.Because, If I wrote sql without parameters I am getting data

Comment: @diiN_ you mean SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KASA WHERE KUL_AD='@AD' ? It not worked

Comment: when you say without parameters, are you doing that directly on the server or through your c# code.

Comment: From what i can see in the code you have provided, there is nothing wrong here. This leads me to believe that the data being looked for simply does not exist in the database itself.

Comment: verify first,is there any data against `egemenhalici@gmail.com`

Comment: Yes there is a data which Kul_Adi=egemenhalici@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your attention. But I think I found my problem.

I don't know but I wrote ? for @ it worked.

```
    MysqlCon c = new MysqlCon();
    MySqlConnection con = c.GetMySqlConnection();
    MySqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
    con.Open();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KASA WHERE KUL_AD=?AD ";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?AD", "egemenhalici@gmail.com");
    int rc = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```